# Kattis Putovanje help c++

Tags: c++, vector

I'm working on the Kattis problem Putovanje (https://open.kattis.com/problems/putovanje).
I have manually inputted the sample inputs and my program's output match the given sample output. But for some reason, Kattis accept my program and says "Wrong Answer" halfway through checking my code. [image: Picture of Kattis Submission box].

Here's the code I'm running for the program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int numFruits, numStomach, temp;
    vector<int> fruitWeight;

    cin >> numFruits >> numStomach;

    for (int i = 0; i < numFruits; i++)
    {
        cin >> temp;
        fruitWeight.push_back(temp);
    }

    int edibleFruits = 0;
    int fruitAmount = 0;
    int vecSize = fruitWeight.size();

   for (int i = 0; i< vecSize; i++)
   {
    if (edibleFruits < numStomach)
      {
        edibleFruits += fruitWeight[i];
        fruitAmount++;
      }
    if (edibleFruits > numStomach)
      {
        edibleFruits -= fruitWeight[i];
      }  
    }

 cout << fruitAmount << endl;
 return 0;
}
```

I don't know why Kattis isn't accepting my answer and any help is deeply appreciated!

Thank you!

Sample input 1

```
5 5
3 1 2 1 1
```

Sample output 1

```
4
```

Sample input 2

```
7 5
1 5 4 3 2 1 1
```

Sample output 2

```
3
```

Comment: Would be nice, if you could describe what the program should do, so the question is self contained and does not rely on external resources. Also, did you try to replicate some of the test cases with an attached debugger? To help us with reproducing (or finding) the error it's always helpful to show the input and expected output.

Comment: This is one of the major problems with most online judge or competition sites: They don't tell you the input so you can't debug your program.

Comment: You always eat the first fruit (if you can) which is possibly not always the optimal solution?

Comment: As a possible hint though: What should happen when `edibleFruits == numStomach`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Just wanted to make sure OP verfied that it works with sample inputs, but yes, that's quite a problem with those contests.

Comment: Thanks @Someprogrammerdude for the hint!  Shouldn't it break from the loop? I tried doing that, and it still fails test case 8/13. I tried fruitAmount++; and that just added an unnecessary integer to my output. I also tried edibleFruits -= fruitWeight[i]; and that didn't work either. :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with this part:

```cpp
if (edibleFruits < numStomach) {
    edibleFruits += fruitWeight[i];
    fruitAmount++;
}
if (edibleFruits > numStomach) {
    edibleFruits -= fruitWeight[i];
}
```

You forget to make `fruitAmount--` when Milslav overeat. Though I would recommend to replace it with:

```cpp
if (edibleFruits + fruitWeight[i] <= numStomach) {
    edibleFruits += fruitWeight[i];
    fruitAmount++;
}
```

It's more compact.

Next part is:

```cpp
 for (int i = 0; i< vecSize; i++)
   {
    if (edibleFruits < numStomach)
      {
        edibleFruits += fruitWeight[i];
        fruitAmount++;
      }
    if (edibleFruits > numStomach)
      {
        edibleFruits -= fruitWeight[i];
      }  
    }
```

You always start to eat from the first fruit and it's not always optimal. You can start to eat starting with any fruit.
For example, the input is the next:

```
3 100
100 50 1
```

With your current code, you will eat `100` fruit and skip all next.
So your answer will be: `1` and the correct one is `2`. Because you can start eating from the second fruit and eat `50` and `1`.

The easiest way to solve it is to have 2 for loops where the first one will iterate over starting index where Milslav will start to eat. And the next loop will iterate till the end. The maximum amount of fruits eaten overall starting indexes is the answer.
Like this:

```cpp
for (int start_eat_from = 0; start_eat_from < N; ++start_eat_from) {
     for (int i = start_eat_from; i < N; ++i) {
     //Eat everything if Milslav can and check that he ate the maximum amount.
     }
}
```

It's going to work because there are going to be only `10^6` iterations and it will be completed in 1 second.

If `N` was bigger than it would be necessary to use some dynamical programming.

**UPD:**

All in all the code will be like this:

```cpp
for (int start_from = 0; start_from < numFruits; ++start_from) {
        edibleFruits = 0;
        int tmpFruitAmount = 0;
        for (int i = start_from; i < numFruits; ++i) {
            if (edibleFruits + fruitWeight[i] <= numStomach) {
                edibleFruits += fruitWeight[i];
                tmpFruitAmount++;
            }
        }
        fruitAmount = max(fruitAmount, tmpFruitAmount);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate your comment. The if statement you provided is really handy and efficient! Unfortunately, I couldn't get the right output using your method. All of the outputs were 1 value short, for example the output I got for sample output 1 was the value of 3, instead of 4. :/

Comment: @Andy I Have updated my post and I have added more detailed code. I just submitted it and it was accepted by Kattis.